# typesafe stack sbt is stuck trying to download scala-compiler.jar on windows

Tags: sbt, typesafe-stack

i installed the typesafe stack.
then opened cmd (i'm on windows 7 64bit)
typed sbt sbt-version like they say in the instructions

it starts but hangs trying to download the compiler from maven. this is how it looks:

C:\Users\nir>sbt sbt-version
Getting Scala 2.9.1 (for sbt)...
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.9.1/scala-compiler-2.9.1.jar ...

after a very long time it returns an error about failed downloads and something about the proxy not configured well. if i try to download the file from a browser it downloads just fine.

could not find a solution to this anywhere. have opened a ticket with typesafe.
anyone have any idea how to get past this?
tnx

Answer (score 2):

ok i got some support from the guys at typesafe.
something was blocking java.exe from hitting the internet.
solved by turning off firewall and antivirus.
after running compile once you can copy the target\staged dir aside and then use it in other projects to run sbt offline.

Answer (score 1):

For reference.

I also had the same problem.

**Simple solution:**

- If you got AVG, disable it! It doesn't work if you have AVG installed and running!
- Disable Windows Firewall ( Start -> Control panel -> Windows Firewall ) and disable.

Comment: it solved the problem thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with SBT  downloading scala-compiler, Turning off the antivirus and firewall solved the problem.